# how to change defaultValues from react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

im trying to do multistep form with React + React Hook Form:

```
const intialState: DeliveryInitialState = {
    deliveryType: null,
    receiver: null,
    sender: null,
    sendTo: null,
    takeFrom: null,
    total: null,
    whoPay: null,
    menu: "method"
};

const ResolvedDeliveryCalc = () => {
    const { options } = useAsyncValue() as IApiData<Array<Option>, "options">;

    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, intialState);

    const menus: Record<string, React.ReactNode> = {
        method: <DeliveryMethod dispatch={dispatch} methods={options} state={state} title="Delivery Method" />,
        receiver: (
            <ReceiverForm
                actionType={ActionTypes.SET_RECEIVER}
                dispatch={dispatch}
                nextMenu="sender"
                prevMenu="method"
                title="Receiver"
                state={state}
            />
        ),
        sender: (
            <SenderForm
                actionType={ActionTypes.SET_SENDER}
                dispatch={dispatch}
                nextMenu="takeFrom"
                prevMenu="receiver"
                title="Sender"
                state={state}
            />
        ),
        takeFrom: (
            <div>take from</div>
        )
    };

    return menus[state.menu];
};
```

As you can see i have 2 different components for Receiver and Sender. I will show only the Receiver cuz they literally the same:

```
const ReceiverForm = ({ actionType, dispatch, nextMenu, prevMenu, title, state }: DeliveryPersonFormProps) => {
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors, isValid },
    } = useForm<Person>({
        mode: "all",
        defaultValues: {
            middlename: state.receiver?.middlename ?? "",
            name: state.receiver?.name ?? "",
            surname: state.receiver?.surname ?? "",
            phone: state.receiver?.phone ?? "",
        },
    });

    const onSubmit = (data: Person) => {
        dispatch({ type: actionType, payload: data as unknown as Person });
        dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.SET_MENU, payload: nextMenu });
    };

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-5 h-[calc(100vh-80px)] pt-12">
            <Title title={title} className="font-bold" />
            <form className="flex flex-col h-full pb-5 gap-5 max-w-[500px]" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <label className="relative flex flex-col gap-4">
                    <span>Surname</span>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="surname"
                        className="border border-solid border-gray-200 px-3 py-2 rounded-lg w-full"
                        {...register("surname", {
                            required: "required",
                        })}
                    />
                    {errors?.surname && (
                        <span className="text-red-500 absolute -bottom-6 text-sm">
                            {errors.surname?.message?.toString() || "error"}
                        </span>
                    )}
                </label>
                <label className="relative flex flex-col gap-4">
                    <span>Name</span>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="name"
                        className="border border-solid border-gray-200 px-3 py-2 rounded-lg w-full"
                        {...register("name", {
                            required: "required",
                        })}
                    />
                    {errors?.name && (
                        <span className="text-red-500 absolute -bottom-6 text-sm">
                            {errors.name?.message?.toString() || "error"}
                        </span>
                    )}
                </label>
                <label className="relative flex flex-col gap-4">
                    <span>Middle name</span>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="middle name"
                        className="border border-solid border-gray-200 px-3 py-2 rounded-lg w-full"
                        {...register("middlename")}
                    />
                </label>
                <label className="relative flex flex-col gap-4">
                    <span>Phone number</span>
                    <input
                        type="tel"
                        placeholder="phone"
                        className="border border-solid border-gray-200 px-3 py-2 rounded-lg w-full"
                        {...register("phone", {
                            required: "required",
                            pattern: {
                                value: /^\+?[78][-\(]?\d{3}\)?-?\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{2}$/,
                                message: "incorrect phone format",
                            },
                        })}
                    />
                    {errors?.phone && (
                        <span className="text-red-500 absolute -bottom-6 text-sm">
                            {errors.phone?.message?.toString() || "error"}
                        </span>
                    )}
                </label>
                <div className="flex items-center mt-10 gap-6 justify-between">
                    <Button
                        className="w-full"
                        type="button"
                        title="back"
                        isBordered
                        isRoundedFull
                        onClick={() => dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.SET_MENU, payload: prevMenu })}
                    />
                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                        className="w-full"
                        title="next"
                        isFilled
                        isRoundedFull
                        isDisabled={!isValid}
                    />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ReceiverForm;
```

But instead of 2 different components i want create one for each person like this:

```
const PersonForm = ({ actionType, dispatch, nextMenu, prevMenu, title, state }: DeliveryPersonFormProps) => {
        const {
            register,
            handleSubmit,
            formState: { errors, isValid },
        } = useForm<Person>({
            mode: "all",
            defaultValues: {
                middlename: (state[state.menu as keyof typeof state] as Person).middlename ?? "",
                name: (state[state.menu as keyof typeof state] as Person).name ?? "",
                surname: (state[state.menu as keyof typeof state] as Person).surname ?? "",
                phone: (state[state.menu as keyof typeof state] as Person).phone ?? "",
            },
        });
    
        const onSubmit = (data: Person) => {
            dispatch({ type: actionType, payload: data as unknown as Person });
            dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.SET_MENU, payload: nextMenu });
        };
    
        return (
            <div className="flex flex-col gap-5 h-[calc(100vh-80px)] pt-12">
                <Title title={title} className="font-bold" />
                <form className="flex flex-col h-full pb-5 gap-5 max-w-[500px]" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    /* same fields */
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    export default PersonForm;
```

but unfortunately this doesn't work. When i save receiver form and render sender form the all fields from receiver form applies to sender form but they should be empty and if i go back from sender form to receiver defaultValues should presist cuz in state.receiver fields already filled.

**What i tried to do:**

i tried to useMemo with state dependency

```
defaultValues: useMemo(() => ({
    middlename: (state[state.menu as keyof typeof state] as Person).middlename ?? "",
    name: (state[state.menu as keyof typeof state] as Person).name ?? "",
    surname: (state[state.menu as keyof typeof state] as Person).surname ?? "",
    phone: (state[state.menu as keyof typeof state] as Person).phone ?? "",
}), [state])
```

also tried to reset form in onSubmit function and useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    reset();
}, [state])

const onSubmit = (data: Person) => {
    reset();
    dispatch({ type: actionType, payload: data as unknown as Person });
    dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.SET_MENU, payload: nextMenu });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

finally i found a way how to do this. Instead of just reseting form in useEffect like this - reset(). I provide new defaultValues for each property

```
const PersonForm = ({ actionType, dispatch, nextMenu, prevMenu, title, state }: PersonFormProps) => {
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { errors, isValid },
} = useForm<IPerson>({
    mode: "all",
    defaultValues: {
        firstname: "",
        lastname: "",
        middlename: "",
        phone: "",
    }
});

React.useEffect(() => {
    reset({
        middlename: (state[state.menu.value as keyof typeof state] as IPerson)?.middlename ?? "",
        firstname: (state[state.menu.value as keyof typeof state] as IPerson)?.firstname ?? "",
        lastname: (state[state.menu.value as keyof typeof state] as IPerson)?.lastname ?? "",
        phone: (state[state.menu.value as keyof typeof state] as IPerson)?.phone ?? "",
    })
}, [state])
```